# Alive and dead. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am *dead* and *alive*.
>
> I am not a zombie nor a cat.
>
> You can bring me back to life,
>   or just let me die.
>
> Everything depends just on *you*.

**Who am I?**

**EDIT:**
As it seems that the answer could be broad, lets remark that "everything depends on you", so that when I say that "you just let me die" I mean that I don´t exist anymore.

**HINT:**

> I am not *alive* or *dead* until you can or can not think on me, the time you can I would exist, the time you can not I won't exist anymore.

**SUPERHINT:**

> Can not think on me = can not remember me.

Comment: Could be smoke or fire. I think its Fire.

Comment: Reminds me of the Schrodinger's cat :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, maybe you're a

> memory

I am dead and alive.

> there are 'dead' memories. And the ones which are being on your mind considered alive.

I am not a zombie nor a cat.

> well, obvious answers. just to remove them from the available pool of choices :)

You can bring me back to life,
or just let me die.

> If you just remember something, aka 'bringing memories back to life'

Everything depends just on you.

> Again. Forgotten memories are dead?..

Comment: Forgotten memories are dead, since they don't exist anymore, as I remark on the edition of the post.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a broad riddle. You could be a...

> Painting

I am *dead* and *alive*.

> A painting is not a living creature. Its components may derive from dead things, such as paper (dead trees) or various animal-product pigments in the paint. But the art can look "alive"; it may have vivid colors and patterns, or may be a painting of people in motion. 
>  
>  This could also be a play on the "[still life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life)" art style, where "still" means unmoving or "dead", and "life" indicates being "alive".

I am not a zombie nor a cat.

> To eliminate the guess of a zombie (undead) or Schrödinger's cat (dead-and-alive animal from a thought experiment).

You can bring me back to life,
or just let me die.

> Paintings may rot and fade over time. Sometimes a painting's owner (or curator in an art exhibit) may have the painting restored in order to conserve its original appearance.

Everything depends just on *you*.

> Art is about evoking emotions in the viewer. A painting is meant to be viewed by "you" (the theoretical observer), otherwise it cannot have an emotional effect.

Comment: I edited the question, so your answer is not valid anymore, as painting still exits even if it does not evoke emotions on you.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> *your* **Passion**

As,

I am dead and alive.

> You can keep your passion alive and dead at *different times*.

I am not a zombie nor a cat.

> Obvious

You can bring me back to life,
or just let me die.

> depending on your will, circumstances and constraints either keeping your passion alive or letting it to die are possible.

Everything depends just on you.

> As it is your own passion !

Comment: this is what i was thinking as well

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Its quite a nice approach to the answer I have in mind. But I will say that passion is not something you can "just let die", as it encourages you to do something, it is something that drives you, so you can't "let it die".